# Vue 3. vue-chartjs and chart.js are compiled with an error on the server: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'labels')

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-props, vue-chartjs

Everything works on localhost, there are no problems, but when the project is compiled on the server, an error occurs when building the vue-chartjs and chart libraries.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'labels'). Experimentally, it was found out that the error appears at the component level. All the propses come to the component correctly, including on the server

```
<template>
    <Line v-if="chartType === 0"
        :chart-options="chartOptions"
        :chart-data="chartData"
        :chart-id="chartId"
        :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
        :plugins="plugins"                
        :css-classes="cssClasses"
        :styles="styles"
        :height="height"
    />
    <Bar v-else
        :chart-options="chartOptions"
        :chart-data="chartData"
        :chart-id="chartId"
        :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
        :plugins="plugins"                
        :css-classes="cssClasses"
        :styles="styles"
        :height="height"
    />    
</template>
  
<script>
import { Bar, Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as
    ChartJS,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    BarElement,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    LineElement,
    PointElement
} from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, LineElement, PointElement)

export default {
    name: 'BarChart',
    components: {Bar, Line},

    props: {
        chartType: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        chartData: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                labels: [
                    '100',
                    '200',
                    '300'
                ],
                datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Your text',
                    data: [100, 100, 100],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                        'rgb(155, 155, 155)'
                    ],
                    hoverOffset: 4
                },
                {
                    label: 'text1',
                    data: [150, 150, 150],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                        'rgb(155, 155, 155)'
                    ],
                    hoverOffset: 4
                },
                {
                    label: 'text2',
                    data: [200, 200, 200],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                        'rgb(155, 155, 155)'
                    ],
                    hoverOffset: 4
                }]
            },
        },
        chartOptions: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
            }
        },
        chartId: {
            type: String,
            default: 'bar-chart'
        },
        datasetIdKey: {
            type: String,
            default: 'label'
        },
        width: {
            type: Number,
            default: 400
        },
        height: {
            type: Number,
            default: 300
        },
        cssClasses: {
            default: '',
            type: String
        },
        styles: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        },
        plugins: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I expected a graph to be displayed, but the component is not going to.
Before the component gets into the library, everything is fine

Comment: So you're saying `yarn build` works on local but not on remote?

Comment: I think you're supposed to provide non primitive (arrays, objects) prop default values as functions. E.g: `chartOptions: { default: {...val}}` should be `chartOptions: { default: () => ({ ...val })}`.